# Should the bottom of a shower enclosure be watertight?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower

I have a newly-installed shower that leaks like crazy. As soon as the water level exceeds the depth of the low-profile tray, I end up with water all over my bathroom floor.

Is this gap in the enclosure the culprit?:

[image: shower tray]

... and if so, do I just need a generous squirt of sealant or is there a component which our builder forgot?

(I'm also looking at why our trap is draining so slowly but that's another topic).

Comment: All this is something your installer needs to address, hopefully he is not paid in full yet to give him incentive to fix it, or at least a builder with integrity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a shower base should be sufficiently water tight to contain an inch or so of water above the drain.  I know that mine does.  Yours doesn't appear to have a lip to contain the water, so that door needs a gasket to both contain the water and prevent damage to the door mechanism.

It sure looks like your builder forgot a seal or chunk of rubber gasket.  If it's recent work, I'd definitely ask about it.

And sure, you want to have your drain running right, but all drains eventually clog.  A working drain doesn't mitigate an unsealed shower base.  You'll need it one day regardless.